# Output of this command Linux

Tags: grep, find, path, exec

Please do anyone has an idea about the output of this command , I have googled a lot about it but I can't find anything useful

```
find . -type f -exec grep -H PATH {} \;
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126915/discussion-on-question-by-askermad789-output-of-this-command-linux).

Answer (score 4):

The command

```bsh
find . -type f -exec grep -H PATH {} \;
```

finds all regular files (`-type f`) in the current directory (`.`) or below, and for each such file executes `grep -H PATH {}` with  `{}`  replaced by the full pathname of the file relative to the current directory.

The `-H` option to `grep` is non-standard but often implemented, and makes sure that each matching line is prefixed by the pathname of the file that the line was found in.  You could change the command to `grep PATH /dev/null {}` instead to force `grep` to always output the pathname of the file that contains the matching lines (standard `grep` does this when at least two files are given on the command line).

The pattern used with `grep` is the string `PATH`.

To summarize: The command finds and outputs all lines from all regular files in the current directory or below, that mention the substring `PATH` anywhere.  Each line is prefixed by the pathname of the file that contains the line.

A snippet of the output that I get when running this in my personal home directory:

```
./Documents/Pathfinder/build/CMakeCache.txt:CMAKE_NM:FILEPATH=/usr/bin/nm
./Documents/Pathfinder/build/CMakeCache.txt:CMAKE_OBJCOPY:FILEPATH=/usr/bin/objcopy
./Documents/Pathfinder/build/CMakeCache.txt:CMAKE_OBJDUMP:FILEPATH=/usr/bin/objdump
./Documents/Pathfinder/build/CMakeCache.txt:CMAKE_RANLIB:FILEPATH=/usr/bin/ranlib
./Documents/Pathfinder/build/CMakeCache.txt:CMAKE_SKIP_INSTALL_RPATH:BOOL=NO
./Documents/Pathfinder/build/CMakeCache.txt:CMAKE_SKIP_RPATH:BOOL=NO
./Documents/Pathfinder/build/CMakeCache.txt:CMAKE_STRIP:FILEPATH=/usr/bin/strip
```

The command could be made more efficient by letting `grep` run on as many files as possible at once, in batches, instead of once for each file:

```bsh
find . -type f -exec grep -F -e PATH /dev/null {} +
```

I've also taken the liberty to change the `grep` command slightly here by adding `-F` so that it treats the string `PATH` as a *string* rather than as a regular expression.  The `-e` option is just used for indicating that the next argument is the pattern (useful if the pattern is later changed to something that may start with a dash, for example).

It's the change from `\;` to `+` at the end of the `-exec` predicate's argument that makes it collect the found pathnames into batches instead of running the utility for each and every one.